# Outlook - Text keeps corrupting, have to resize window to fix

Tags: microsoft-outlook

My outlook has been bugging out lately. Text keeps corrupting like the screenshot shows. Any ideas how to solve?

[image]

Comment: Have you updated your display drivers recently?

Comment: I installed chipset, wlan and touchpad drivers. No graphic card drivers. The laptop has 2 graphic cards, one internal and one external.